# How to give the xls file link in Ruby on Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

```
How to give the xls file link in ruby. This is my file path 
link_to "Excel", "/#{RAILS_ROOT}/public/reports/10014_ByNetwork.xls", :target=>"_blank"
```

when i given above link that is converting like this

```
 <a href="//home/kiran/shekar/wavespot/public/reports/10014_ByNetwork.xls" target="_blank">Excel</a>
```

So its not working. actually i need like this

```
<a href="file:///home/kiran/shekar/wavespot/public/reports/10014_ByNetwork.xls" target="_blank">Excel</a>
```

Please give me exact path...

Comment: You are aware, that this link will only work on your computer and will not work on any other, right?

Comment: yes i need in my computer only

Answer (score 2):

@Gagan Your syntax is incorrect. You should test your answers before posting them. This is the correct way:

```
<%= link_to 'Excel',"/reports/10014_ByNetwork.xls", target: "_blank" %>
```

OR

```
<%= link_to 'Excel',"/reports/10014_ByNetwork.xls", :target=>"_blank" %>
```

You have missed out the comma after the second closing double quotes.

Answer (score 1):

if you have more than one file to download and you have to use different links along your views I could recommend you the next approach too:

Add a *download xls* **get resource** and **route helper** to your `routes.rb` file like:

```
get "downloads/xls/:id" => "downloads#xls", :as => :download_xls
```

In your controller, for my my example I'll use `app/controllers/downloads_controller.rb` we will need to add the **xls** action to stream data with `send_file`:

```
def xls
  if params[:id]
    send_file("#{Rails.root}/public/reports/#{params[:id]}.xls", 
              filename: "#{params[:id]}.xls", 
              type: 'application/excel', 
              disposition: 'attachment')
  end
end
```

You can read more about it here:
http://apidock.com/rails/ActionController/DataStreaming/send_file

And finally in your view you'll use the `link_to` helper with our declared above  `download_xls_path` route and the filename as param:

```
<p>
  Click to download: </br> 
  <%= link_to "NameOfYourXlsFile.xls", download_xls_path(NameOfYourXlsFile) %>
</p>
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure that you need file:// link? It is not operated by rails server and will work only on your machine. Maybe it will be better to generate link like this: "http://you_server_url.org/public/file.xml". It works fine on local and remote app, and you can manage file-sending by controller action.

Answer (score 0):

Try this in your view file:

```
<%= link_to 'Excel',"/reports/10014_ByNetwork.xls" :target=>"_blank" %>
```