# ruby on rails export an excel data file

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails, export-to-excel

I am trying to design a website that allows anyone visiting the site to download an excel file.  The excel file just stores data that I would like to make publicly available.  I am using ruby on rails, and was wondering if there is an easy way to store my excel spreadsheet (maybe in the assets folder?) and make a link on my webpage that when clicked downloads the spreadsheet.
Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out by looking at a related post:
[How to give the xls file link in Ruby on Rails?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26504501/how-to-give-the-xls-file-link-in-ruby-on-rails)
and looking at the answer by hernanvicente

Answer (score 2):

You can use CSV export (works with Excel pretty well) since Ruby has a well implemented CSV feature into the software.

```
class UsersController < ApplicationController
  def index
    @users = User.all

    respond_to do |format|
      format.html
      format.csv { send_data @users.to_csv, filename: "users-#{Date.today}.csv" }
    end
  end
end
```

Also, you have to `require` it in your config/application.rb:

```
require 'csv' 
require 'rails/all' # Or something resembling to this.
```

In your model, add this into it:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  def self.to_csv
    attributes = %w{id email name}

    CSV.generate(headers: true) do |csv|
      csv << attributes

      all.each do |user|
        csv << attributes.map{ |attr| user.send(attr) }
      end
    end
  end

  def name
    "#{first_name} #{last_name}"
  end
end
```

Source: [GoRails (Video)](https://gorails.com/episodes/export-to-csv?autoplay=1), [RailsCasts](http://railscasts.com/episodes/362-exporting-csv-and-excel?view=asciicast)

Comment: Thanks for the response.  I'm still a little confused (sorry I'm new to coding), where would I upload my csv that I want to export?  It is not made from an active record, but rather is a file that I have and want to make available.

Comment: Rails relies on ActiveRecord (database) with a model of some method to pass in. For example, if you want to contain records that has username, location, etc, that will need to be stored in the database. Updated with more sources

Comment: so there isn't a way to put a excel file somewhere in the rails project and create a link to it in html?

Comment: No, at the moment, the `assets` folder will be only used for stylesheets, javascripts and images (when applicable). I researched through the official documentation from [Rails](http://http://guides.rubyonrails.org/asset_pipeline.html), it only supports that I mentioned above.